# Stack canary flag -fstack-protector-strong enables by default?

Tags: gcc, compilation

I am trying to compile snippet of code without using `-fstack-protector-strong` flag.

Snippet :-

```
// Hello.c
#include<stdio.h>

/* Commenting out or not using the string.h header will cause this
 * program to use the unprotected strcpy function.
 */
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
char buffer[5];
printf ("Buffer Contains: %s , Size Of Buffer is %d\n", buffer,sizeof(buffer));
strcpy(buffer,argv[1]);
printf ("Buffer Contains: %s , Size Of Buffer is %d\n", buffer,sizeof(buffer));
}
```

Command:- `gcc -g -O2 Hello.c -o Hellotest`

```
/home/ktpl/checksec/checksec.sh/checksec --file=Hellotest
RELRO           STACK CANARY      NX            PIE             RPATH      RUNPATH      Symbols         FORTIFY Fortified       Fortifiable     FILE
Full RELRO      **Canary found**      NX enabled    PIE enabled     No RPATH   No RUNPATH   72) Symbols       Yes   2               2               Hellotest
```

I see that my binary gets `Canary found` though i have not compiled the code with flag `-fstack-protector-strong`. Does stack canary flags enables by default?

Answer (score 0):

The default is set when gcc itself is built, which may have been by your OS or package distributor.  Run `gcc -v` and see if the `--enable-default-ssp` option is present.

You can turn it off for an individual compilation by using `gcc -fno-stack-protector`.  If you really want it off permanently, you may have to recompile gcc from source, making sure to exclude `--enable-default-ssp` at the `configure` step.

Comment: Thanks @Nate for response, i could not see `--enable-default-ssp`  from `gcc -v`. These are enabled/disable flags i could see :- `--enable-libsanitizer --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-libcilkrts --disable-gnu-indirect-function --disable-gnu-unique-object --disable-multilib`

Comment: Is there any other possibility of enabling stack canary implicitly? So that i will verify.